# C# DateTime to MySqlDateTime convert

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

Im using MySQL connector to receive data form database and put values to dataset->dataGridView. Then i need to change value in date column when i click on column with checkbox:

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Продано")
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkbox = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
            bool isChecked = (bool)checkbox.EditedFormattedValue;
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
    }
```

I need to convert DateTime to MySqlDateTime, to insert value in some column.
Now i have error, that expects MySqlData type.
`Unable to convert System.DateTime value to MySQL date/time`

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 5):

MySQL DateTime is in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

The following code will take your **C# DateTime** and convert it to **MySQL DateTime**:

```
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Now;
string MySQLFormatDate = dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
// Now write it to your database...
```